# Error in using tag in command line when using liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I wanted to use the liquibase tag functionality. At first, I run the following command into cmd (with liquibase.properties set up etc)

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changeLog.xml update
```

where the changeLog.xml contains as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="ivan">
        <createTable tableName="customer">
            <column name="id" type="varchar2(42)" />
            <column name="name" type="varchar2(42)" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

and no error occurs.

Now, I want to tag the current database state, by using the following command:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changeLog.xml tag exampletag
```

and I've also tried using the following command

```
liquibase tag exampletag
```

alas, both attempts failed with the same error message, as follows

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown Reason
```

How do I properly tag a database in the current state, by passing the commands via command line? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is the stack trace I obtained from running the first command. And also, I am using Liquibase 3.2.0

```
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Connected to N603066@jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.111.48.125:1521:orcl
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1402468965639 as 984dfd7dd9a2496bb4b3c74eeafa6a64
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from N603066.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT LOCKED FROM N603066.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1 FOR UPDATE
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Lock Database
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE N603066.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'LD418102Y (10.111.48.204)', LOCKGRANTED = to_date('2014-06-11 14:42:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0
INFO 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT MD5SUM FROM N603066.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from N603066.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM N603066.DATABASECHANGELOG
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: UPDATE N603066.DATABASECHANGELOG SET TAG = 'exampletag' WHERE DATEEXECUTED = (SELECT MAX(DATEEXECUTED) FROM N603066.DATABASECHANGELOG)
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Release Database Lock
DEBUG 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE N603066.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
INFO 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown Reason

SEVERE 6/11/14 2:42 PM: liquibase: Unknown Reason
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.tag(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:306)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.tag(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:834)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.tag(Liquibase.java:695)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:939)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:170)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.tag(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:304)
    ... 5 more


For more information, use the --logLevel flag
```

Comment: Can you run with --logLevel=DEBUG to get a stacktrace? Also, which version of Liquibase are you running?

Comment: Hi @NathanVoxland, I've just added details on the stack trace. For your information, I am using Liquibase 3.2.0...   And also, I also found a similar behaviour when I want to use <sqlFile> inside a <rollback> tag, when I attempted to do rollback for the said changeset. Should I file another question with regards to this issue as well?

Comment: I think this and the other is more of a bug than a stackoverflow question. Can you log them both as issues at liquibase.jira.com ?

Comment: @Nathan, I can't open a new issue on Liquibase JIRA. I've registered as ivanwangsa, yet I can't find a button to open a new issue.

Comment: I made a change to the permissions to hopefully help. If you are still having troubles let met know at nathan@liquibase.org

Comment: @Nathan, I've filed the issue on JIRA: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1923. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan, I have the same problem. Is there an rss feed or email list where we can get "pinged" when you release new versions?

Comment: I always post releases to blog.liquibase.org which has an rss feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in Liquibase 3.2.1.